# ImageView scaling delayed

Tags: java, image, performance, javafx, scaling

I have an ImageView called fillViewer that is set up to fill the screen with an image. If the image is narrower than the window, it is scaled so that it matches the windows width, and if it is wider it is scaled to match the height, so that an image of any aspect ratio can fill a window of any aspect ratio. When I scale the window, I also want the background image to scale. However, occasionally when scaling the window there is a small black edge on the right side not filled by the image. From my testing, the black bar gets bigger the faster the window is scaled, so the image scaling seems to have trouble "keeping up" with the window scaling. Any idea how to fix this?  Here is the code that scales the image:

```
    mainStage.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldH, Number newH){
            if (!mainStage.isFullScreen()){
                if (proportionalScale){
                    //windowBorders is the outer borders of the window, calculated by Stage size - Scene size
                    mainStage.setWidth(  ( ( newH.doubleValue() - windowBorders.getHeight() )  * windowRatio) + windowBorders.getWidth() );
                }

                //fillRatio is the ratio of the background image, windowRatio is the ratio of the window (Ratio = Width/Height)
                if (fillRatio < windowRatio){
                    fillViewer.setFitWidth(mainScene.getWidth());
                }
                else{
                    fillViewer.setFitHeight(mainScene.getHeight());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

setPreserveRatio and setSmooth are both true for this viewer. Setting setSmooth to false does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I guess I'll answer myself. The image doesn't have time to scale when the window is dragged up or down in size too fast. There are some workarounds to this both on the user and programmer side, but in the end, I decided on this solution:

Whenever my resize listener is triggered, I set a boolean called needsScaling to true. Then I listen for an event (currently a mouse release, I might try to listen for any mouse click or keyboard event). When I detect that event and needsScaling is true, I set needsScaling to false and trigger my scaling code.

If anyone has an *actual* solution rather than a workaround I'd be glad to hear it.